# IPhone Range Slider

Tags: iphone, uikit, range, uislider, rangeslider

I know there is a UISlider but does anyone already made RangeSlider ( with two thumbs ?)
or knows how to extend the uislider?

Comment: KennyTm look at the creation date. sigh

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can directly extend UISlider, you probably need to extend UIControl.

Anyway, this is what I did and created this: http://github.com/doukasd/DoubleSlider

Have a look and let me know if you find it useful. You might also want to have a look at my blog post which includes a video showing how it works (to make sure we are talking about the same thing): http://dev.doukasd.com/2010/08/double-slider/