# iPhone : Min Max Slider Control

Tags: iphone, uislider

does anyone know of a slider control with 2 sliders on it so that you can select min and max values?

Comment: Brilliant, post it as a answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: [IPhone Range Slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681933/iphone-range-slider)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, nothing like this exists in the core widgets provided by apple, but you could probably create one.